# ORA-01858 error-to_date() in sql

Tags: oracle, dbvisualizer

I'm using the query

```
select to_date(DateString,'MM/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss')
from tableName
where to_date(DateString,'MM/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss') between to_date('2015-10-01','yyyy-MM-dd') and to_date('2015-10-31','yyyy-MM-dd');
```

the result is: ORA-01858:a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected. Here, the DateString column data type is Varchar2, not nullable. Values of DateString is:

```
10/11/15 20:14
10/21/15 11:36
10/25/15 17:50
```

I don't understand where I have done mistake.

Comment: If you don't have a seconds component, why is that in the format string?

Comment: @Gordon I removed it from format string. Received the same error now also.

Comment: You probably have malformed data in your table.

Comment: If the column has malformed data, it should work for few years/months. Even I tried with different years/months, it is not working...